# I'd like to pen-test my website, what tool would you recommend?

Tags: penetration-test, web

I have downloaded my website/database and recreated it on a Centos 7 server locally. I'd like to give it a good hammering with a view to finding and fixing any vulnerabilities.  Can anyone recommend a piece of software that would perform this function for me? Open source would be great!

Comment: people are down voting this because you are 1, asking for a software recommendation and 2, the title of this question alone made the whole community cringe! It is not as simple as a single tool or even many tools but more of an understanding what to look for. anything you plan to do with your current knowledge would be pointless.

Comment: Ditto.  Love your comment, @TheHidden.  You captured my reaction perfectly (except for the downvote part).  I am still laughing.  Good show.  +1 - I see this is closed so let me extend what you are saying here by suggesting that sean b take an online course in this subject.  And as he learns this is a great place to ask specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the kind of vulnerability you're looking for, there are many commercial and open source tools out there.
Some of the most popular are:

- [Nessus](https://www.tenable.com/products/nessus-vulnerability-scanner)
- [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/)
- [burpsuite](https://portswigger.net/)

And you can try the free trial.

I also would recommend you read something from [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/About_OWASP) like:

- [Vulnerability Scanning tools](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Vulnerability_Scanning_Tools)
- And the [TOP 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project)

Your question is too broad, [try being more specific or make some research and reformulate the question](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

There is no tool or tools that will find / fix all vulnerabilities. Some tools will find some vulnerabilities, and some basic ones are easy to find, but this isn't an area where an unskilled person can use a tool and be "safe"

Professional testers use tools, in addition to manual techniques, information gathering, vulnerability chaining, etc...